# jQuery: Issue with replacing span content programmatically

Tags: jquery, html, find, closest

I have a div with the below structure (using Bootstrap 3) and inside this a span with the class "`votes`":

**My HTML:**

```
<div>
    Views: <span class="badge views">12</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Votes: <span class="badge votes">0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#">Comments:</a> <span class="badge comments">5</span>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btnVote">Vote</i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**My jQuery:**

The following jQuery returns me the content of this span which is always a number (in this case: 0):

```
var votes = $(this).closest('div').find('.votes').text();
```

Now I am trying to replace the content of this span, resp. to add 1 to it by clicking on the button in the same div. 
I used the following but this doesnt change it:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.votes').text(parseInt(votes) + 1);
```

OR

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.votes').html(parseInt(votes) + 1);
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: That should work, albeit inefficiently. Can you create an MCVE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it should be okay, although I'd always use a radix on `parseInt`. But you can do it much more efficiently, rather than looking up the element twice:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.votes').text(function(i, text) {
    return parseInt(text, 10) + 1;
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/waquzo/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot - let me check.

Comment: Same result as in my case. It doesnt change the votes content.

Comment: @user2571510: That's not surprising, since what you had should work. Again, can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I figured it out. The $(this) didnt work as this was only in the Ajax function but not in the main function so I had to pass the ID first so that it knows which button I am referring to. Thanks for the help though !

Answer (score 1):

It seems working fine or i miss something?

HTML:

```
<div>
    Views: <span class="badge views">12</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Votes: <span class="badge votes">0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#">Comments:</a> <span class="badge comments">5</span>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btnVote">Vote</i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".btnVote").click(function(){
    var votes = $(this).closest('div').find('.votes').text();
    $(this).closest('div').find('.votes').text(parseInt(votes) + 1);
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hrptyuq0/)**

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesnt work for me but I also dont get an error message. Is there anything else that could prevent this from working ? I have multiple divs like the above on my page but as I use closest this shouldnt matter.

Comment: @user2571510: Did you check Demo? the demo doesn't work? demo working fine absolutely but if the code is not working in you project, so it's necessary to provide more details or create a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks - the demo works fine. I am checking something on my code now that might affect this.

Comment: I figured it out. The $(this) didnt work as this was only in the Ajax function but not in the main function so I had to pass the ID first so that it knows which button I am referring to. Thanks for the help though !